# Slice all strings in a list from their first '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to remove first RemoveThisX\n from list

`['RemoveThis1\nDontRemove\nDontRemove','RemoveThis2\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis3\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis4\nDontRemove\nDontRemove']`

Trying to remove RemoveThis1\n, RemoveThis2\n, RemoveThis3, RemoveThis4\n

Final result need to be

`['DontRemove\nDontRemove','DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove']`

Comment: `"\nhello\n".replace("\n", "", 1)` will return `'hello\n'`. Do with that what you will. See [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: What have you tried?  It seems a comprehension like `["\n".join(string.split("\n")[1:]) for string in my_list]` would work?

Comment: What exactly do you want to removed, the first `'\n'` or the `'RemoveThisX1'`? What would the result look like?

Comment: Trying to remove RemoveThis1, RemoveThis2, RemoveThis3, RemoveThis4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a_list = ['RemoveThis1\nDontRemove\nDontRemove','RemoveThis2\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis3\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis4\nDontRemove\nDontRemove']

result = [item[item.find('\n')+1:] for item in a_list]
print(result)
```

```
['DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove']
```

Comment: Thank you! Working.

Answer (score 1):

```py
test_list = ['RemoveThis1\nDontRemove\nDontRemove','RemoveThis2\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis3\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis4\nDontRemove\nDontRemove']
result = ["\n".join(item.split("\n")[1:]) for item in test_list]
print(result)
```

Output will be:

```
['DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove', 'DontRemove\nDontRemove']
```

Comment: Thank you, its working also.

Answer (score 1):

assuming:

```
initial_list = ['RemoveThis1\nDontRemove\nDontRemove','RemoveThis2\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis3\nDontRemove\nDontRemove', 'RemoveThis4\nDontRemove\nDontRemove']
```

I would recommend using either the map function:

```
mapped_list = list(map(lambda x: x[x.find('\n') + 1:], initial_list))
```

or list comprehension:

```
comprehended_list = [string[string.find('\n') + 1:] for string in initial_list]
```

Both should produce the asked list.